# wk buffer error when running .get_WKT Oracle Spatial function on SDO_GEOMETRY objects

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, oracle-spatial

My company runs Oracle 19 and we recently (October 25) installed the October Oracle quarterly patch. Since the patch was applied, I have been unable to run the .Get_WKT function without frequently experiencing the following error

```
Runtime Exception
ORA-13199: wk buffer merge failure
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 729 
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 768
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY", line 36
```

The command I ran which generated this error is

```
select a.sfref, a.geom4326.Get_WKT() from feat_geom a where sfref between 62000 and 63000;
```

SFREF is a primary key indicator for each geometry.

Prior to the quarterly patch being applied, I would get a list of hundreds of HUGECLOB objects, which I could interrogate individually or through other code, and would link to some of our other business processes. One other anomaly is that the .Get_WKT code sometimes gives HUGECLOBS for a particular geometry, and sometimes it fails, giving the wk buffer error.

What I am looking for in this message please is whether anyone has
(i) come across a similar error when dealing with .Get_WKT
(ii) whether this error was encountered by people prior to the October 2021 Oracle patch
(iii) what resolution you were able to apply to solve the issue?

Thanks

Sean

Comment: That looks like a bug. You need to raise the issue with Oracle support. They will ask you for a reproducible case. Try to narrow down the issue to one or two geometries that fail. Also validate the failing geometries. It may be that they are invalid, but that the previous versions were more forgiving.

Comment: Hi Albert, thanks for your comment. I've raised it with Oracle but am not having much success. That's why I decided to raise it here - to see if others are experiencing the same anomaly.

Comment: If you are OK to post your SR number, I can take a look.

Comment: SR 3-27581685651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just for information, my Oracle third party support have been in discussion with Oracle themselves on this and it turns out this issue is a known bug

Bug 33561708 : ORA-13199: WK BUFFER MERGE FAILURE

There is a patch for this, which is available from Oracle at https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugMatrix?id=33561708

It has been applied to my database instance and resolved my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue on one of our Oracle 19c databases after applying the Oct2021 Release Update.  We were able to solve the problem by backing out the RU.  Since we wanted current security patches, we applied the Jul2021 RUR1 in its place and re-tested.  The problem did **not** recur after after the RUR was applied, suggesting that the issue was caused by one of the non-security bug fixes or minor feature updates included in the RU.

For those unfamiliar with OraCorp's RU/RUR patching strategy, it's important to understand that July 2021 RU Revision 1 **contains all of the latest security fixes as of Oct 2021**.  For details, please review MOS Doc #2285040.1, which explains how Release Updates and their Revisions are related.  I'll note that while our team has maintained documentation on deployment of each quarter's RURs, this is the first time we've actually had use for a Revision.

**UPDATE:**  Using RURs is obviously a temporary fix.  To allow use of up to date RUs, Oracle has been releasing Spatial Patch Bundles to address issues resulting from conflicts between RUs and Oracle Spatial.  For My Oracle Support customers, information on these can be found in MOS DOC #2514624.1.  So far these have been issued for every 19c RU (but NOT for RURs) since 19.9 (Oct2020) through Jan2022, though generally some time after the RU.  To date no Spatial PB has been issued for the April 2022 RU, so we hope these may no longer be necessary, but other customers may have encountered Spatial issues that we have not.